# Hive-Hbase integration

Tags: hbase, hive

I am trying to integrate Hive  and Hbase together. For that I went through cwiki and several other blogs and posts, but couldn't do it.I am using `Hive-0.7.0` and `Hbase-0.90.4`. Could someone provide me some info on the minimum(and must) requirements to do that? Do I need a fully distributed Hbase setup in order to use Hive and Hbase together ? When I tried it on standalone mode I was able to add the hive-hbase handler, but could not move beyond that point.

Comment: What errors were you getting? Without knowing more information, we can't help you.

Comment: I am getting Hmaster not running error, it is running though..I am able to use Hive and Hbase separately but not togather..Also I am able to use them together when I use Cloudera's distributions...Do I require pseudo distributed Hbase configuration in order to use Hive-Hbase together???

Answer (score 0):

what kind of errors are u getting? 
What exactly did u install? The configuration very (for someone without experience) difficult.

I would recommend you "Cloudera". Its a Hadoop distribution which includes HBase Hive.
You can do a express installation on a single machine (pseudo mode). Everything is configured automatically (HBase Hive, Zookepper and so on) 
The only thing u need is RedHat or CentOS.

"MapR" is an other alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You hadn't specify the errors. But what i can get from your question is:

"**As you have download the hbase version Hbase-0.90.4** download the version of hive that range in the same like Hive-0.9.0" It will work fine.

for hive hbase integration check this jar files appended

bin/hive --auxpath **/hadoop/hive-0.9.0/lib/**hive-hbase-handler-0.9.0.jar,**/hadoop/hive-0.9.0/lib/**hbase-0.92.0.jar,**/hadoop/hive-0.9.0/lib/**zookeeper-3.3.4.jar,/hadoop/hive-0.9.0/lib/**guava-r09.jar** -hiveconf hbase.master=localhost:25000

/hadoop/hive-0.9.0/lib/  defines the notification where your hive resides which may according according to your location scheme.

Rest all are the jars needed to configure.

After it run successfully you can create a table to check whether it is working or not
CREATE TABLE demo_hTable(key int, value string) STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,cf1:val") TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name" = "demo_table_one");

This demo_table_one must resides in the Hbase before you run this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed Hbase-0.90.4 and hive 11 then it should work properly. You can try following command to create table in hive and map it through hbase:

in hive CLI:

Hive> create table default.hbase_hive_tbl(id int, name string,age int, desig string, city string) stored by 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,cf1:name,cf1:age,cf2:desig,cf2:city") TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name" = "xyz");

Here hbase_hive_tbl is  created in hive and is mapped with the hbase table XYZ.
Data loaded in the hbase or hive can be seen in any table .

I think it can solve your problem. Please let us know in case of more clearance.